# Regularisation of ill-conditioned matrix-vector problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, condition-number

I have a linear* problem which arises from an integro-differential system, and writes:
$$
(\mathbf{I}+\lambda \mathbf{A})x = b
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a real full matrix, size $n\times n$, but is not symmetric and has some zero eigenvalues. I know what these eigenvalues correspond to.

When $\lambda$ increases (but is still much smaller than 1) the condition number of $\mathbf{I}+\lambda \mathbf{A}$ (let's call it $\mathbf{K}$) deteriorates extremely rapidly (to $10^{10}$ and more). Even with a direct solver (luckily $n=100$ is enough for me) the results become meaningless.

I have no certainty, but I believe this is linked with the zero eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.
Is there a way I could exploit my knowledge of the corresponding eigenvectors to regularize the numerical resolution?

(* note that this is actually the fixed-point linear problem that I am solving, the original problem has $\lambda=\lambda(x)$)

**EDIT:**
$\mathbf{A}$ itself has indeed a very large condition number (numerically evaluated by numpy with L2-norm), $10^{19}$, with $\sigma_{\min} = 1.8e-07$  and $\sigma_{\max} = 3.2e11$ ($\sigma_{\min}$ should analytically be 0 of course, since as said above, $\mathbf{A}$ has a 0 eigenvalue). Its largest eigenvalue has modulus about 600, here is the complete spectrum for $n=102$

[image]

Comment: If matrix $A$ has large real negative eigenvalues, then for some small $\lambda$, 0<$\lambda \ll$1 the eigenvalues of $I+\lambda A$ can become zero , so the matrix $I+\lambda A$ becomes singular. Is that what is going on?

Comment: Interesting. Does the problem come from some imaging, tomography etc? What is the physical meaning of A, $\lambda$?

Comment: No, it's a mechanical problem in 2D half-space that we've brought to a 1D segment using kernels. $A$ includes in some involved way a 3rd order differentiation, which is partly borne on the kernels, and $x$ contain degrees of freedom of a $P_3-C^1$ (Hermite) finite element representation of the velocity.

Comment: If there are large singular values in $K$, then $A$ must have large norm itself. What is the range of $\sigma_{\min}(A), \sigma_{\max}(A)$? What are the maximum and minimum norm of its eigenvalues?

Comment: My suspicion is that the very large s.v. of $K$ "correspond" to the 0 eigen values of $A$, which themselves correspond to the fact that constant or linear velocities are associated with 0 eigen value.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Indeed - although it's not so clear what happens, I'll add these details in the post

Comment: I don't think it works like that. If $Av=0$, then $Kv=v$, so $v$ isn't a problematic direction (unless $\sigma_{\min}(K) \approx 1$, which could be the case if $A$ is badly scaled, but in this case they correspond to small eigenvalues, not large).

Comment: @MaximUmansky: deleting my comment, it seems that indeed I have such an eigenvalue. I was sure I had ruled that out, I'll have a further look.

Comment: Let's assume for now that those zero eigenvalues are the cause of the problem. I assume that if you have $m$ zero eigenvalues you should see $m$ "small" singular values at 1 and then a big gap before the next one; is that the case? On the other hand, if you have more than $m$ small singular values, then even taking care of a dimension-$m$ subspace via ad-hoc tricks won't improve the conditioning.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: it's actually the other way around, 2 large singular values and many small ones. The reason of my thinking was that I believe the large singular values could originate from small eigenvalues, isn't that the case? Maybe I'm completely mistaken about that. I lack intuition about s.v. relation with eigenvalues.